# How to get index a list of a list

Tags: python-3.x

```
x = [[1,2,3],[2,4,5]]
```

How do you get the index of 2 when the list in a list of a list?

I have tried below but it is not working

```
a = x.index(2)
```

The output I want to see is like 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` in a list comprehension that filters the output based on whether `2` is in the current sub-list:

```
[i for i, s in enumerate(x) if 2 in s]
```